# Python madlib while loop issue

Tags: python

My attempt at a Python switch statement basically. Cant get this loop to work. just prints same thing each time.

```
choice = input("Do you want to play a game? (y) or (n)")
while choice == "y":
while True:
    print("1. Fun story")
    print("2. Super Fun story")
    print("3. Kinda Fun story")
    print("4. Awesome Fun story")
    print("5. Some Fun story")

    choice2 = int(input("Which template of madlib would you like to    play(Enter the number of your choice"))

if choice2 == 1:
    noun1 = input("Enter a noun: ")
    plural_noun = input("Enter a plural noun: ")
    noun2 = input("Enter another noun: ")
    print("Be kind to your {}-footed {}, or a duck may be somebody’s {}".format(noun1, plural_noun, noun2))


else:
    print("Goodbye")
```

Comment: Please fix your indentation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Very easy to create problems when using "while True". You may want to end your program with a proper exit condition, but a few adjustments to your indentation and a break statement solves the problem. Before, the if conditional was never reached, as it was outside of the second while loop, causing the story choices to be printed out again after your choice2 was made. This should work:

```
choice = input("Do you want to play a game? (y) or (n)")
while choice == "y":
    while True:
        print("1. Fun story")
        print("2. Super Fun story")
        print("3. Kinda Fun story")
        print("4. Awesome Fun story")
        print("5. Some Fun story")

        choice2 = int(input("Which template of madlib would you like to play (Enter the number of your choice) "))
        break # break out of this while loop to reach if/else

    if choice2 == 1:
       noun1 = input("Enter a noun: ")
       plural_noun = input("Enter a plural noun: ")
       noun2 = input("Enter another noun: ")
       print("Be kind to your {}-footed {}, for a duck may be somebody’s {}".format(noun1, plural_noun, noun2))

    else:
        choice = "n" # Assume user does not want to play, reassign choice to break out of first while loop (exit condition to prevent infinite loop of program)
        print("Goodbye")
```